# specific ID in react-admin list

Tags: react-admin

would like to get the id of a row when I click on a button or somewhere on the row inside the list/Datagrid component of react-admin,
I am completely new to react js and react-admin as well.
WOuld appreciate for any kind gesture

Comment: 1. You need to read the docs of your component library. Maybe looking for a `onClick` prop which gives you the data you seek.

Comment: am using react-admin and need to get id of row in list component, but can#t find any solution, if u have any idea, please let me know

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. Otherwise no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

React-admin exposes a hook called `useRecordContext` that lets you access the record used by the current component. In a Datagrid, this lets you access the record of the row.

So you can create a component like so:

```
import { useRecordContext } from 'react-admin';

const MyButton = () => {
    const record = useRecordContext();
    const handleClick = () => {
        // the current row id is record.id
        // do something with it
    };
    return <button onClick={handleClick}>Do stuff</button>;
}
```

Then, use that component as a child of `<Datagrid>`:

```
const MyList = () => (
    <List>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="title" />
            <MyButton />
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```

More information at https://marmelab.com/react-admin/useRecordContext.html